# How to post to a facebook fan page's wall with C#!

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook

I have a fan page on my Facebook account.

While posting of regular updates to that page's wall from my asp web application. It always goes to my personal Facebook account not to my fan page.

So how I can make it access my fan page only and post on it?

Here is my simple code ...

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FaceBookConnect.API_Key = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FBAPIKey"];
    FaceBookConnect.API_Secret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FBAPISecret"];

    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        string code = Request.QueryString["code"];
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(code))
        {
            Dictionary<string, string> data = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            data.Add("link", "string here");
            data.Add("picture", "string here");
            data.Add("caption", "string here");
            data.Add("name", "string here");
            data.Add("message", "string here");
            FaceBookConnect.Post(code, "me/feed", data);
        }
    }
}

protected void btnPost_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FaceBookConnect.Authorize("publish_actions", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FBRedirectURL"]);
}
```

Comment: @Martha ASP is a synonym for asp-classic.  So it happens quite often that someone selects ASP when they mean ASP.net.  I will retag.

Comment: You need to acquire a page access token first, and then use that to make the post. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens#pagetokens

Comment: @CBroe, you should add your comment as an answer ;) That's exactly the issue here.

Answer (score 0):

You need to acquire a page access token first, and then use that to make the post.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens#pagetokens